# Replace HQL subquery by a variable

Tags: hql, hibernate-query

Hi I am trying to convert my SQL query to HQL.

The query I am trying to use looks like this

```
select lieu from StorageLocationRef location 
Where (cast(:disabled as boolean) = true or 
    location.id in (select otherClass.lId from OtherClass otherClass where someConditions)
    location.id in (select otherClass.lId2 from OtherClass otherClass where someConditions)
    location.id in (select otherClass.lId3 from OtherClass otherClass where someConditions)
    )
```

In SQL, I used to implement this with SQL **WITH** statement. I don't know how to make it in HQL

Is there any option to replace the select subquery by a variable

`(select otherClass.lIdX from OtherClass otherClass where someConditions)`

Can Sombody help please.